# Do i need a continue command or not. Why?

Tags: java

I am making a random generated number game. Computer randomizes a number 1-50 and user needs to guess that number in order to win. I need some help with using continue command in one line where program asks user to play the game over or quit the game.

Today we learned about continue and break commands. Professor made a little game to showcase using of continue and break. I copied the code to analyse it and deleted an continue command in one line just to see will it still work, and it did. Why did it work? I have marked the line with //<---HERE

```
while (true) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 50) + 1;
        boolean found = false;

        System.out.println("A number 1-50 is picked, try to guess it!");
        System.out.println("--Testing purpose only--" + randomNum);

        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {

            System.out.print(i + ". Try: ");
            int chosen = input.nextInt();

            if (chosen == randomNum) { 

                found = true;
                System.out.println("You've guessed it");
                break;

            } else if (chosen < randomNum) {

                System.out.println("Number you are guessing is higher");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Number you are guessing is lower");
            }

        }

        if (found) {

            System.out.println("Victory");
            System.out.println("Guessing number was: " + randomNum);

        } else {

            System.out.println("Defeat! Guessing number was: " + randomNum);

        }
        System.out.print("Start over? (type \"yes\")");
        String s = input.next();
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            System.out.println("**************************");
            **continue**;                                         //<---HERE
        } else {
            System.out.println("End.");
            break;
        }

    }
```

I am expecting an error if there is no continue command in marked place but there is no error and the program works fine.

Comment: You are correct. Tell your professor they used a redundant `continue;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the last statement of your infinite while loop. It has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

The continue line does not do anything in this case as it is the last statement in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense for your code to generate an error just because you removed `continue`, the continue command will let you tell your program to skip to the next iteration. So without continue your code continues to execute normally.